# output figures sticked together even with %2d

Tags: c

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 3
void getScore(int score[], int size)
{
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    scanf("%2d", &score[i]);
    return;
}

int sortScore(int score[], int size)
{
    int max;
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1; j<size; j++)
        {
            if(score[i]<score[j])
            {
                max=score[i];
                score[i]=score[j];
                score[j]=max;
            }
        }
    }
    return score[N];
}

void output(int score[], int size)
{
    printf("\nIn descending order: ");
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
        printf("%2d", score[i]);

    printf("\n\n");
    return;
}
```

And this is my result: [image: result]

I'm wondering why there is no space between 15 and 10 and when I add a space before %2d:

```
printf(" %2d", score[i]);
```

it will be unaligned.

Thank you very much for your time and patience for answering my question!

Comment: Please copy your text if you want to show your output. Don't post a screenshot for pure text only content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `"%2d"` as in the code shown, then 2 or more places will be used (2 for numbers `-9` to `99` with a leading blank for numbers `0` to `9`; more for numbers outside this range).  When printing 15, that's two places; the next output is 10, and there's no need for a space; the last number is 5, which needs a blank and digit to occupy two places.  When you add the space to the format, then you get at least one space between numbers.

If you want things to work with a single space between each number, but not before the first number, you can play games like:

```
int data[] = { 15, 10, 5 };
const char *pad = "";
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    printf("%s%d", pad, data[i]);
    pad = " ";
}
putchar('\n');
```

I find this technique works nicely for me.

Answer (score 0):

Usually that may be better left-aligned with something as:

```
 printf("%-6d", score[i]);
```